Count the number of times a combination of values is present in each row
I  have a database of character values.
df = data.frame(col1 = c("value_1","value_3","value_3","value_2"),
                col1 = c("value_1","value_1","value_4","value_2"),
                col1 = c("value_1","value_2","value_1","value_2"),
                col1 = c("value_3","value_3","value_3","value_2"),
                col1 = c("value_2","value_3","value_4","value_2"))

I want to count the number of time a combination of values is present in a row.
The combination is not exact, for example if I want the combination of value_1 and value_2, it's the combination of having both values AT LEAST once.
The combination is an input, and the number of element in the input may be different.
Input:
comb = c("value_1","value_2")

Desired output
out = 2

One solution is to use the ifelse() function for each modality in comb, by looping on the number of element in comb, create a dummy variable for each element, make the product of each, then just sum the product.
But I wonder is there is a more elegant solution ?

Is it meant row-wisely?

Here is a quick way:
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("value_1","value_3","value_3","value_2"),
                col1 = c("value_1","value_1","value_4","value_2"),
                col1 = c("value_1","value_2","value_1","value_2"),
                col1 = c("value_3","value_3","value_3","value_2"),
                col1 = c("value_2","value_3","value_4","value_2"))

comb <- c("value_1","value_2")

apply(df, 1, function(x) all(comb %in% x)) |>
  sum()

Note that this will internally convert df into a matrix so that apply can process each row.  There may be quicker/more efficient ways to do it (possibly using one of the map functions from the purrr package).

Using rowSums twice:
> sum(rowSums(combn[1L]==df) * rowSums(combn[2L]==df) > 0L)
[1] 2

Wrapping into a function f:
f = \(df, combn) {
  stopifnot(is.data.frame(df), is.character(combn), length(combn)==2L)
  sum(rowSums(combn[1L]==df) * rowSums(combn[2L]==df) > 0L)
}
f(df, combn)
# [1] 2


If your comb always consists of 2 elements, you can try match + rowMeans like below
sum(
  !rowMeans(
    `dim<-`(match(as.matrix(df), comb), dim(df)),
    TRUE
  ) %in% seq_along(comb)
)

Or, for general length of comb, you can use
sum(
  rowMeans(
    apply(
      outer(as.matrix(df), comb, `==`),
      3,
      rowSums
    ) > 0
  ) == 1
)

